# How to allow both import ES5 and ES6 to my npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am new to npmjs package publishing and recently published my 1st package successfully. But since it's written in ES5 style. It is accessed only via "require"

```
const smiley = require('smiley-id');
```

What should be done to make it accessible via import statement also? like this

```
import smiley from 'smiley-id';
```

or/and

```
import { smileyId } from 'smiley-id';
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "ES5 style". Those are nodejs modules.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html has all the info you need. Also https://2ality.com/2019/10/hybrid-npm-packages.html

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121593/how-can-i-publish-an-npm-module-with-both-commonjs-and-es6-versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` is part of the CommonJS module system (also known as `cjs` modules) whereas `import` and `export` are used in `es2015` module system (also known as JavaScript modules, `es6` modules or `esm` modules).

You can use `import` for both `cjs` and `esm` modules, but you cannot use `require` for `esm` modules. This means that in an `esm` module (or source file which you will compile with Typescript `tsc` or Babel or bundle with Webpack) you can already import your package, as it is, with `import`. However, you cannot use named imports. Instead you have to destructure the imported item afterwards.

If you want to distribute it as an `esm` package, this is also possible and it comes with some advantages, out of which the most important is related to tree-shaking. To distribute it as an `esm` module, you tell your build tool to output `esm` modules. This is different for different tools. For`tsc` for example you specify `--module es6` (there are multiple targets that output `esm` modules). For Webpack, Babel and Rollup, the procedure is different.

Comment: Thanks, @fast-reflexes for helping me out. I'll update my module to ES6.